# Zend selects all columns

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db

In the following code:

```
$selectColumns= array('user_id.user_email', // inner join the data from user_id and user_details
                            'user_details.first_name', 
                            'user_details.last_name');
        $result = $handle->select()->from('user_id', $selectColumns)
                                   ->where('user_id.uid=?', $uid)
                                   ->join('user_details', 'user_id.uid = user_details.uid')
                                   ->query(ZEND_DB::FETCH_OBJ);
```

Zend selects **all** the columns in the table, not just the requested ones.

How can I select only some?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is in your `join()` method call:

```
->join('user_details', 'user_id.uid = user_details.uid')
```

The optional third argument is columns from *this* table.  If the argument is absent, it defaults to `user_details.*`.

Note that you added qualified columns from both tables in the `from()` table, but this has no effect on the default of `user_details.*`.  Sorry, but `Zend_Db_Select` just isn't smart enough to keep track of all that.

You can make the `join()` call add no columns by passing an empty array:

```
->join('user_details', 'user_id.uid = user_details.uid', array())
```

The qualified columns you added in the `from()` call should still be there.  To verify this yourself, print the SQL:

```
print $result . "\n"; // calls __toString() method on Zend_Db_Select object
```

Answer (score 6):

Add another parameter to your join at the end -- an empty array. That will tell it to select no columns from the join. With the code you have now, you are selecting all columns from the joined table.

```
->join('user_details', 'user_id.uid = user_details.uid', array())
```

Comment: +1 for getting there first, +1 for Bill for the extra detail. Why do only Zend people vote Zend people up?